# Major number allocation for a UART chip interfaced to IMX SOC for Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am developing a UART device driver for a external uart chip interfaced(Memory mapped with address and data lines) to a freescale IMX SOC.

As of now I am using a Major number 4 (TTY_MAJOR) which is used by 8250 chip since because I dont have 8250 chip in my system and minor number also the same used by 8250.

Please let me know this major number assigment is correct or not?

If this is wrong please let me know how can i allocate major number for this driver.

I am working on linux 3.2 kernel, I am developing this driver under serial core substysem of linux.
Using api uart_register_driver to register a uart device and platform_driver_probe api to register platform driver.

Answer (score 0):

Static allocation of character device major/minor numbers is discouraged. The static allocation scheme has been maintained for backward compatibility, but nowadays you should use dynamic allocation with the [alloc_chrdev_region](http://dev.man-online.org/man9/alloc_chrdev_region/) function:

```c
alloc_chrdev_region(&device_node, base_major_number, device_count, device_name);
```

This function allows the kernel to choose a free major number for you when the module is loaded instead of you having to choose a compile-time constant major number.

Arguments:

1. `&device_node`
   Address of your device node
2. `base_major_number`
   Lowest major number you are requesting. The kernel will look for a free major device number that is greater than or equal to this number and assign it to your device. Simply pass `0` to give the kernel the most flexibility.
3. `device_count`
   Number of devices your driver is registering - this is how many minor numbers you are requesting.
4. `device_name`
   Name of your device

Later on in your driver, you can extract your device numbers with the `MAJOR()` and `MINOR()` macros:

```c
#define DEVNAME "MY_DEV"
#define DEVCOUNT 1

/* within __init routine, assuming you have a static device_node declared
 * elsewhere in your driver
 */

int major_num;
int minor_num;
int alloc_status;

status = alloc_chrdev_region(&device_node, 0, DEVCOUNT, DEVNAME);

if (status){
    printk(KERN_ERR "Registering %s driver failed with code %d.\n", DEVNAME, status);
    /*go perform cleanup for failed major allocation*/
}

printk(KERN_INFO "Allocated %d device(s) at major %d, minor %d.\n", DEVCOUNT, MAJOR(device_node), MINOR(device_node));
```

I think for a UART device attached to your system, your selection of Major number 4 is on the right track if you feel you *need* static allocation for some reason, but dynamic allocation is the preferred method.

Comment: The second argument is 'unsigned baseminor': first of the requested range of minor numbers